# How to get limited page numbers visible in pagenation list to display a list of items?

Tags: jsp, jstl

```
<c:if test="${paging.pageCount > 1}">
<c:if test="${not empty searchkey}">
<c:set var="pagingpath1" value="&key=${searchkey}&value=${searchvalue}" />
</c:if>
  <div style=" background:#f5f5f5; border:1px solid #dedede; height:30px; width:985px;  margin:20px auto">
        <div class="pagDiv_1"><a>Results:<span><c:out value="${ paging.page }"> - </c:out> - <c:out value="${ paging.pageCount }"></c:out> ( total: <c:out value="${ paging.count }"></c:out> )</span></a></div>
    <div class="page-nav">
                <a>Pages:</a>
                <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${paging.orderStatus}">
                <c:set var="pagingpath" value="&order=${paging.order}&dir=${paging.direction}">
                </c:set>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise><c:set var="pagingpath" value=""></c:set></c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
                <a class=lftarrow href="#">Previous &#9668;</a>
                <c:forEach var="pid" varStatus="status" begin="1" end="${paging.pageCount}" step="1">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${pid == paging.page}"><span class="cur-page"><b>${ pid }</b></span><label>|</label></c:when>
                    <c:otherwise><a class="page" href="consultant_list.htm?p=${pid}${pagingpath1}&selectiontype=${selectiontype1}&searchtext=${textbox1}">${ pid }</a><label>|</label></c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
                </c:forEach>
                                            <a class=lftarrow href="#">&#9658; Next</a>

    </div>

  </div>
  </c:if>
```

[image]

The image attached has the listing page in which I am working .

The code snippet is to display the pagenation in the footer.

How to make only say 4 page numbers visible at once and on click of "Next" the other pages must be visible?

Comment: Just a tip: don't do that in JSP/JSTL/EL code. Prapare the work for the view in a controller, in Java. Regarding the code, it's just a matter of only generating the links for some pages around the current one, and potentially a link for the first and last one. integer arithmetics.

Comment: Thanks ..me too thinking the same.any best logical idea for doing it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Tag for this which can display only relevant pages (few around the current page and start & last page), which can be used at multiple places and will be cleaner approach as well.

You can create a tag, which will accept these parameters:

- a) the url you want to hit on selection of each page.
- b) the number of links you want to show at a time, say 10.
- c) total page size.

In this tag you can add this code to show only few page numbers (say 10) with first & last page link. Now this thing can be used as a component which can be used in various places of your application.

Comment: I dint get you .. can u re-explain

Comment: You can create a tag, which will accept these parameters: a) the url you want to hit on selection of each page. b) the number of links you want to show at a time, say 10. c) total page size. In this tag you can add this code to show only few page numbers (say 10) with first & last page link. Now this thing can be used as a component which can be used in various places of your application.

Answer (score 0):

DisplayTag is a wonderful little library that makes what you want to do easy..

http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/

Alternatively, if the size of your dataset's aren't very large in size (bytes) the following Jquery library is also cool:

http://datatables.net/